# How to Add Phone Number Column at WooCommerce Customer Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to add a new column on the Customers page in WooCommerce.

To be more specific the column would be to display the phone.

The table is on the main WooCommerce Dashboard Customers page (admin.php?page=wc-admin&path=%2Fcustomers).

[image]

On the Wordpress.com Forum, moderators just submit all threads to the WooCommerce support page to hire a partner agency.

I couldn't find the snnipet or function for this anywhere.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.